# Current code displays a message on the system. I want to write my own message to display

Tags: xslt, message, display

This is the current code. And it displays 'Application updated' I want to add more text to the message. Any help would be great, I am a complete novice.

```
<xsl:if test="/Root/InfoMessage">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/Root/InfoMessage/@description"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: You should be able to just add the text you want after the `xsl:value-of` statement. For example `<xsl:value-of select="/Root/InfoMessage/@description"/><br />Extra Message`

Comment: Amazing thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your text before and after the `<xsl:value-of>`. If you like, you can wrap your text in an `<xsl:text>` element, but you don't have to.

```
<xsl:if test="/Root/InfoMessage">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                some text before
                <xsl:value-of select="/Root/InfoMessage/@description"/>
                some text after
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:if>
```